# Windows 8 Won't Boot After Update

Tags: windows-8, boot

Sorry if this is the wrong division of stack exchange. Anyway:

Yesterday I did the Microsoft updates on my Lenovo IdeaCentre Windows 8 computer. When it rebooted though, the screen was just black. I tried manually rebooting it to no avail. It shows the Lenovo screen but not the loading dots. I can still open the BIOS but nothing else.

I've tried everything. Waiting long times with it on or off. Trying different key combos. I'm afraid the windows might have been corrupted but hoping not.

Comment: It doesn't sound like a software problem it sounds like a hardware problem.

Comment: Soooo... Any ideas to fix it?

Comment: Does the BIOS allow you to get into any options to restore/recover the OS?

Comment: I can set it back to default settings. Should I try that? Will I lose my files?

Comment: Depends what you mean by that exactly.

Comment: What settings should I look at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the BIOS, set CSM to enabled. Now it works.